# C++ Partial Template Specialization:Undeclared identifier error

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

The goal of writing this code was to get a better understanding of partial template specialization. I'm trying to partial specialize the class Vector with three different bools.

I have an enum(for my bool) defined as:

```
enum MY_BOOL
{
   YES,
   NO,
   MAYBE
};
```

For my primary template class I have

```
template<class A,MY_BOOL,class B>
class Vector{};
```

And the partial specialization class I have is

```
template<MY_BOOL b>
class Vector<A,YES,B>{};
```

The compiler is complaining that `A` and `B` are undeclared identifiers and that the partial specialized `Vector` has too few arguments. Doesn't complain about 'YES' This confuses me because `A` and `B` were already defined in the primary template class. I shouldn't need to put them back in the parameter list of the partial specialized class because the point of that parameter list is to only have the variables that I want specialized.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` actual types in your partial specialization?  Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @NathanOliver they're not like int or char but there purpose was to be passed in a different template struct. The keyword class should of dealt with this?

Comment: You can't do a specialization like that.  `A` and `B` only apply to `template<class A,MY_BOOL,class B>
class Vector{};`.  In `template<MY_BOOL b>
class Vector<A,YES,B>{};` they do not exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver so in other words I have to include A and B in my template parameter list for the partial specialized template class?

Comment: Yes, but then it wouldn't be a partial specialization.  Why are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to make three different partial specialization for the main primary template vector  that uses 1 of the 3 enums. Vector 1 has YES Vector 2 has NO and Vector 3 has MAYBE

Comment: I am guessing you wanted to specialize for `YES`. For that, use `template<typename A, typename B> class Vector<A, YES, B>{};`

Comment: Okay.  You'll need to do that opposite of what you have.  I'll add an answer that shows to to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
template<MY_BOOL b>
class Vector<A,YES,B>{};
```

Since `A` and `B` aren't specified, you get a compiler error.  It is not going to use the `A` and `B` from the primary template, it will only use the types/value defined in the specialization.

Since you want a specialization for each of the enum values you can do that like

```
template<class A,MY_BOOL,class B>
class Vector {};

template<class A, class B>
class Vector<A, YES, B>{ /* YES stuff */ };

template<class A, class B>
class Vector<A, NO, B>{ /* NO stuff */ };

template<class A, class B>
class Vector<A, MAYBE, B>{ /* MAYBE stuff */ };
```

And now you have a specialization for each of the enumerations.

Comment: @BrogrammerDude It works fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cec9655d639f8fb2)

Comment: if I were to implement member functions do I need to do anything fancy besides including the template parameter list above the member function in a separate .cpp file?

Comment: @BrogrammerDude [You should not put the template in a cpp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).  For all of the out of line member definitions you would nee something like `template<class A, class B>
return_type Vector<A, MAYBE, B>::function_name(parameters) {}`

Answer (score 0):

A partial specialization for YES would look like:

```
template<class A, class B>
class Vector<A, YES, B>
{ ... };
```

The meaning of partial specialization is that you provide different template arguments than the base template and fill in the missing template parameters of the base template yourself.